# Securing Data Protection Passwords

Tags: security, password-protection

At the moment, I am building a system that deals with sensitive data. For this, I am encrypting all the information with a key that is saved (for the moment) within the script. Can anyone suggest any methods that the key could be secured somewhere secret, but is available to the system (for a multitude of users, not just the owner and administrator)?

Comment: Can't you store that key in a database that is available to the system?

Comment: @stackSamaritan nope, cos the connection credentials to the database is encrypted. although I can see the benefit of using the database for the key store, if the server gets hacked (to a file system level which is my present concern), then that throws all security out the window. I am trying to find a way to secure those credentials (among other sensitive data) from any kind of breach

Comment: That is where public-key cryptography helps. Even, if the keys are leaked there are only a threat but cannot cause a breach possibly because without the knowledge of encryption algorithm/key agreements.

Answer (score 0):

In Diffie–Hellman key exchange scheme, each party can generate a public-private key pair. The public key can be shared with each other prior to information exchange. The private keys are not shared and work with the shared public key to decrypt the message. This is public key cryptography.